# Where do I put my config in this axios request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, create-react-app

If I put my config as the second argument, my cancellation token (third arg) gets ignored. However I need the Authorization header because this get request will be (but isn't yet!) Behind authentication middleware on my node API. So my question is: Where do I put my config?

```
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
    },
  };

  const getBoards = async (cancelToken) => {
    try {
      if (localStorage.getItem("token") == null) {
        throw new Error();
      }

      const response = await Axios.get("/boards", {
        cancelToken: cancelToken.token,
      });
      setBoards(response.data);
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const request = Axios.CancelToken.source();
    getBoards(request);
    return () => {
      request.cancel();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: checkout [global-axios-defaults](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults)

Comment: I thought there'd be a way to put it in the actual request. Never mind, this solves it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

pass them in the same object.

```
const response = await Axios.get("/boards", {
    headers: {},
  cancelToken: cancelToken.token,
});
```